# how to redirect stdout to a file in NuShell?

Tags: nushell

how to redirect some command output to a file in `NuShell`?

In zsh/bash we can redirect output of `ls` command to a file as below

```
ls > fileList.txt
```

how can we do the same in NuShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect/save into a file, use the `save` command (see the [manual](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/save.html)).

However, `save` takes strings as input, while `ls` provides records. You can convert those records into strings by defining how.

One way, if your primary interest lies in saving the looks, is to explicitly render the table as shown in your shell using the `table` command (see the [manual](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/table.html) which even lists `ls | table` as one of the examples):

```bash
ls | table | save fileList.csv
```

But if you are more interested in the data conveyed, re-format it into a datatype of your choice using `to` (see a [list of formats](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/categories/formats.html)). For example, to re-format it as CSV use `to csv`, for HTML use `to html`, for JSON use `to json` etc. There is also `to text` which simply lists all records line by line with their key names prepended. Its [manual page](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/to_text.html) even lists `ls | to text` as one of the examples.

```bash
ls | to csv | save fileList.csv
# or
ls | to html | save fileList.html
# or
ls | to json | save fileList.json
# or
ls | to text | save fileList.txt
# etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

To update this answer based on more recent Nu (v 0.84 as I write this):
Nushell now has redirection operators: `out>` `out+err>`, similar to sh-shells `1>` `2>&1` etc.  Can be used as follows:

```
> 10 + 20 >out t.t
> cat t.t
30
```

Redirection operators compared to `save`.

- redirection `out+err>` (abbreviated `o+e>`) can capture both streams to a single file.  `save f.f --stderr f.f` refuses to save both streams to same file.
- redirection operators do not require the preceeding `| save`.  They are, er, postfix operators in an expression.
- redirection operators always overwrite the file.  They do not have an append option.
- like `save`, the input for redirection operators must be string or converted to string via `to json` as suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

Below command saved the `ls output` in json format and retrieved in exact format.

```
ls | to json | save -f fileList.json
open fileList.json
```

use `--force` option to overwrite file.

command `help save` is your friend on terminal:

```
> help save                                                                                                                                                     06/06/2023 10:50:48 PM
Save a file.

Search terms: write, write_file, append, redirection, file, io, >, >>

Usage:
  > save {flags} <filename>

    ...more info here...
    ...more info here...

Examples:
  Save a string to foo.txt in the current directory
  > 'save me' | save foo.txt

  Append a string to the end of foo.txt
  > 'append me' | save --append foo.txt

  Save a record to foo.json in the current directory
  > { a: 1, b: 2 } | save foo.json

  Save a running program's stderr to foo.txt
  > do -i {} | save foo.txt --stderr foo.txt

  Save a running program's stderr to separate file
  > do -i {} | save foo.txt --stderr bar.txt
```