# how to redirect stderr to a file in NuShell?

Tags: nushell

Here is what I tried

```
ls | to json | save fileList.json
open fileList.json | from json | save error.log
open fileList.json | from json | save --stderr error.log
```

It didn't save anything to file `error.log`

FYI, added the (useless)second part `| from json` to create error message to save it.

Tried below example from `help save` but didn't work:

```
> do i {} | save foo.txt --stderr foo.txt
Error: nu::shell::cant_convert

  × Can't convert to Closure.
   ╭─[entry #62:1:1]
 1 │ do i {} | save foo.txt --stderr foo.txt
   ·    ┬
   ·    ╰── can't convert string to Closure
   ╰────
```

[related question on saving stdout to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76403457/how-to-redirect-some-command-output-to-a-file-in-nushell/76420128#76420128)

Comment: Note: The example from the manual, `do -i {} | …`, uses `-i` as argument (you have provided `i` without the dash, making it just a string).

Comment: thanks @pmf, without the `-` it works. Not sure, why they put the (confusing) `-` there in an example. It will trip many as more people start using the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `save` correctly, but you are missing that nu's internal commands do not "print to stderr".

If you want to catch an internal command (e.g. `ls`) that might fail, use `try` and `catch`:

```bash
try { ls nonexistent.file } catch { echo "mishap" | save error.txt }
# or
try { ls nonexistent.file } catch { |e| echo $e.msg | save error.txt }
```

If you want to capture the output that an external command (e.g. cat) has sent to STDOUT or STDERR in a `do` block, you can use `save` just like you have tried:

```bash
do { cat nonexistent.file } | save out.txt --stderr err.txt
```

But with external commands you can more directly also use `out>`, `err>`, and `out+err>` to channel their raw streams:

```bash
cat nonexistent.file out> out.txt err> err.txt
```

Finally, you might also be interested in using `complete` which provides you with `stdout`, `stderr`, and `exit_code` as keys in a record (which you can then further process like with `to text | save …` or `to json | save …` or `get stderr | save …` etc.):

```bash
do { cat nonexistent.file } | complete
```

```
╭───────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ stdout    │                                                  │
│ stderr    │ cat: nonexistent.file: No such file or directory │
│           │                                                  │
│ exit_code │ 1                                                │
╰───────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```